# leetcode JavaScript Merge Two Sorted Lists

Tags: javascript, algorithm, while-loop, linked-list

I wonder why my code got timeout,when I sove that problem in leetcode,I think its the condition of the while-loop that cause it, but could somebody please tell me why?
I try to use chatGPT but it cannot give a exact answer.

I think it may be because I made an endless loop. I saw the answers of others and find that they use the ListNode itself in the condition and content of while-loop, and I use ListNode.next,I understand their method, but still have no idea why my method does not work.

```
/**
 * @param {ListNode} list1
 * @param {ListNode} list2
 * @return {ListNode}
 */
var mergeTwoLists = function (list1, list2) {
  if (!list1) return list2;
  if (!list2) return list1;
  const dummy = new ListNode(0);
  let l = dummy;
  let l1 = new ListNode(0);
  let l2 = new ListNode(0);
  l1.next = list1;
  l2.next = list2;
  while (l1.next && l2.next) {
    if (l1.next.val < l2.next.val) {
      l.next = l1.next;
      l1 = l1.next;
    } else {
      l.next = l2.next;
      l2 = l2.next;
    }
    l = l.next;
  }
  if (!l1.next) l.next = l2.next;
  if (!l2.next) l.next = l1.next;
  return dummy.next;
};
```

Comment: Please don't post code as an image, type the code. If you don't have it anymore, type it from scratch.

Comment: thank you for your advice, I type it again~ And I will avoid it next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's take an example input of:

```
list1 = [1, 3]
list2 = [2, 4]
```

We can visualise the state when the loop is about to start. At that time three dummy nodes have been created, referenced by `dummy` (and `l`), `l1` and `l2`:

```
dummy  l
  ↓    ↓
┌────────────┐
│ val: 0     │
│ next: null │
└────────────┘
      l1             list1     
      ↓                ↓      
    ┌────────────┐   ┌────────────┐   ┌────────────┐
    │ val: 0     │   │ val: 1     │   │ val: 3     │
    │ next: ────────►│ next: ────────►│ next: null │
    └────────────┘   └────────────┘   └────────────┘

    ┌────────────┐   ┌────────────┐   ┌────────────┐
    │ val: 0     │   │ val: 2     │   │ val: 4     │
    │ next: ────────►│ next: ────────►│ next: null │
    └────────────┘   └────────────┘   └────────────┘
      ↑                ↑
      l2             list2
```

### Iteration 1

In the first iteration the `if` condition is true, after the two assignments in the `if` block and the final `l = l.next` have executed, we have this:

```
dummy
  ↓
┌────────────┐
│ val: 0     │
│ next: ──────────┐
└────────────┘    │
                  │  list1  l1  l
                  │    ↓    ↓   ↓ 
    ┌────────────┐│  ┌────────────┐   ┌────────────┐
    │ val: 0     │└─►│ val: 1     │   │ val: 3     │
    │ next: ────────►│ next: ────────►│ next: null │
    └────────────┘   └────────────┘   └────────────┘

    ┌────────────┐   ┌────────────┐   ┌────────────┐
    │ val: 0     │   │ val: 2     │   │ val: 4     │
    │ next: ────────►│ next: ────────►│ next: null │
    └────────────┘   └────────────┘   └────────────┘
      ↑                ↑
      l2             list2
```

The second dummy node (the one that was initially referenced by `l1`) no longer has a reference, so it can be garbage collected. No problem.

### Iteration 2

In the second iteration, we compare 3 with 2, and so the `else` block is executed. When its two assignments and the final `l = l.next` have executed, we get:

```
dummy
  ↓
┌────────────┐
│ val: 0     │
│ next: ──────────┐
└────────────┘    │
                  │  list1  l1
                  │    ↓    ↓ 
                  │  ┌────────────┐   ┌────────────┐
                  └─►│ val: 1     │   │ val: 3     │
                     │ next: ──┐  │   │ next: null │
                     └─────────│──┘   └────────────┘
                  ┌────────────┘
    ┌────────────┐│  ┌────────────┐   ┌────────────┐
    │ val: 0     │└─►│ val: 2     │   │ val: 4     │
    │ next: ────────►│ next: ────────►│ next: null │
    └────────────┘   └────────────┘   └────────────┘
                       ↑    ↑   ↑  
                     list2  l2  l
```

Here we see a first problem: the node with value 3 has become orphaned! There is no more reference to it, and so it is for ever lost (it can be garbage collected). In the next iteration we can omit another dummy node (originally referrenced by `l2`) as well. But the problems will mount up...

### Iteration 3

In this iteration we no longer have the node with value 3. The comparison is now between 2 and 4, and so the `if` block executes. The first of the statements in the `if` block creates a loop: `l.next = l1.next` because `l1.next` is the same as `l`. We can stop the analysis there, because this loop will cause the variables `l`, `l1` and `l2` to get stuck in that loop:

```
dummy
  ↓
┌────────────┐
│ val: 0     │
│ next: ──────────┐
└────────────┘    │
                  │  list1  l1
                  │    ↓    ↓ 
                  │  ┌────────────┐
                  └─►│ val: 1     │
                     │ next: ──┐  │
                     └─────────│──┘
                  ┌────────────┘
                  │  ┌────────────┐   ┌────────────┐
                  └─►│ val: 2     │◄─┐│ val: 4     │
                     │ next: ────────┘│ next: null │
                     └────────────┘   └────────────┘
                       ↑    ↑   ↑  
                     list2  l2  l
```

The main problem in your code is that you don't keep `l1` and `l2` *ahead* of the already merged part of the list. The correct way to do it is to have `l1` and `l2` reference the two input lists that are still unaltered (not merged), and `l` should reference the tail of the merged part. So what we see above, where `l1` and `l2` reference nodes of the *same* list, should never happen.

As you already know about the correct code, I will leave it at that. I hope it clarifies what went wrong.